# How to update the xcode

Tags: xcode, installation

Do I need to delete the old xcode and download the new xcode dmg file? or can i keep the old version and install the new dmg,so that it replaces the old one?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do all of this through the App Store on your Mac. Simply open the App Store, click on Updates, and then click Update by the Xcode icon. This will replace the older version with the new version. But don't worry, all of your projects will still be saved and compatible with the new version.